How do find the rank of a matrix when all elements are variables?
I'm trying to find the rank of the following matrix
$$ A = \begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \cr
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \cr
\end{pmatrix} \text{where} \ a_{ij} \in \Bbb{R} \ \text{for all} \ i,j \in \text{{1,2,3}}
$$
I know Rank(A) = Dim(Span({$c_1, c_2, c_3$})) where $c_1, c_2, c_3$ are the column vectors of A. But I'm completely lost on how to find the span.

Hint: the column space and the row space have the same dimension. So the rank $r$ can be at most $2$. The case $r=0$ is trivial. Can you distinguish between $r=1$ and $r=2$? I mean: under what condition (about the rows) is the rank $1$?

$ \begin{Bmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \cr 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 \cr 1 \end{pmatrix} \end{Bmatrix} $ is a basis for the set of column vectors and has dimension 2 so Rank(A) = 2 but i dont get how Rank(A) $\le$ 2

@confusedstudent The column space is a subspace of $\mathbb R^2$ so it has dimension at most $2$. Or, if we use the fact that dim(col space) = dim(row space), another way to see it is that there are only two columns, so they span a space of at most dimension two.

@confusedstudent The column space isn't necessarily the span of $\begin{Bmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \cr 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 \cr 1 \end{pmatrix} \end{Bmatrix}$ i.e. all of $\mathbb R^2$. That depends on the entries $a_{ij}$.

right, because if $a_{11} = a_{21}, a_{12}=a_{22}$ and $a_{13}=a_{23}$ then $ \begin{Bmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \cr 1 \end{pmatrix} \end{Bmatrix} $ is a basis for the column vectors in which case Rank(A) = 1?
But how do we know Rank(A) $\neq$ 3 or higher?

For the rank to be 3 or higher, the row space would need to be rank 3 or higher, but there are only two rows and so their span can never be more than 2 dimensions.
